# Dealing with N by 1 matrices in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Given a numpy array of size `(n,)` how do you transform it to a numpy array of size `(n,1)`.

The reason is because I am trying to matrix multiply to numpy arrays of size `(n,)` and `(,n)` to get a `(n,n)` but when I do:

```
numpy.dot(a,b.T)
```

It says that you can't do it. I know as a fact that transposing a `(n,)` does nothing, so it would just be nice to change the `(n,)` and make them `(n,1)` and avoid this problem all together.

Comment: Also have a look at `np.atleast_2d` if you want to simplify things to work with either 1D or 2D input in this case.  `atleast_2d` will make it a row vector rather than a column vector, however. If you'd like 1D arrays to become column vectors (and 2D to be left alone), you can use either `np.column_stack([array])` or `np.c_[array]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reshape (-1,1)` to reshape `(n,)` to `(n,1)`, see detail examples:

```
In [1]:

import numpy as np
A=np.random.random(10)
In [2]:

A.shape
Out[2]:
(10,)
In [3]:

A1=A.reshape(-1,1)
In [4]:

A1.shape
Out[4]:
(10, 1)
In [5]:

A.T
Out[5]:
array([ 0.6014423 ,  0.51400033,  0.95006413,  0.54321892,  0.2150995 ,
        0.09486603,  0.54560678,  0.58036358,  0.99914564,  0.09245124])
In [6]:

A1.T
Out[6]:
array([[ 0.6014423 ,  0.51400033,  0.95006413,  0.54321892,  0.2150995 ,
         0.09486603,  0.54560678,  0.58036358,  0.99914564,  0.09245124]])
```

Comment: What will that (reshape(-1,1) ) do to an arbitrary (n by k) numpy array? I just hate so much having to treat insert code to treat (n by 1) as a special case just cuz numpy does.

Comment: Do u mind explaining a little verbally what ur solutions does? (It looks like it works but how did u know to do that)?

Comment: For a `(n,k)` array, it will be reshaped into `(n*k, 1)`.

Comment: Sure, see the very last example in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape, basically when you set a dimension to be `-1` that dimension is therefore unspecified and its size will be inferred. When you have a `(n,)` array, with the total size of `n`, `reshape(-1,1)` will infer the first dimension to be `n`, in order to keep the total size unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `None` for dimensions that you want to be treated as degenerate.

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
a[:]
a[:, None]

In [48]: a
Out[48]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [49]: a[:]
Out[49]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [50]: a[:, None]
Out[50]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Comment: So a[:,None] makes it a column vector of size (n by 1)? What does it mean degenerate?

Comment: A singleton dimension that does not contain data, but which needs to exist for sizing purposes. There are facilities to make it have arbitrary size-0 dimensions.